# Error in C program, using VS2017 for the first time

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

I getting code 0 error while compiling very simple code. How do I solve it?
I using VS 2017 for the first time.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("My name is Haim");
}
```

[image: a busy cat]

The two rows in the middle are not supposed to be there!

Haim

Comment: what are you trying to ask?

Comment: FYI, 0 is the "error code" to say everything was fine...

Comment: The compiler showing this error. Why and How do I make it disappear?

Comment: In VS2015 it doesn`t happen!

Comment: There is no compiler error in the question.

Comment: Post the error message as text and not as an image

Comment: 1) time to read a good C book to learn; 2) time to learn using you IDE too

Comment: Its time for Microsoft not to touch something that works fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main()` should return some exit code. So int should be as the return type.

In the other hand exit code `0` means, that everything was succesfull, [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status).

Comment: Ok. But how do I make it disappear in the console?

Comment: Never mind I solved it. Stupid compiler!!!